# Как отправить PUT запрос c body через cUrl

Tags: php, curl, put

Не получается отправить запрос, PUT без body корректно работает, через POST body нормально отправляется, а вот body + PUT никак

```
$this->client = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($this->client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen(serialize($params))));
curl_setopt($this->client, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($this->client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
curl_setopt($this->client, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($this->client);
```

В переменнной params что-то типа:

`{
      "sector_id": 5,
      "row": 10,
      "seat": 5,
      "seat_id": 334022,
      "price": 1500
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, если отправляется PUT без body, обязательно должен присутствовать заголовок 'Content-Length:', причем неважно что там стоит, я ставил 1, а если есть и PUT и body, тогда 'Content-Length:' быть не должно